# php-fpm keeps locking up

Tags: php, php-fpm

For some reason, php-fpm keeps locking up and/or hanging. It works for a little while, and then it will randomly just 'hang' for a long time upon trying to load a webpage. There's absolutely nothing in my php-fpm.log about it, and I have no idea how to track down the problem otherwise. Can you guys help me track it down by pointing me in a new direction?

```
CentOS 6.2

[root@3AC19 ~]# php-fpm -v    
PHP 5.3.9 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Jul  5 2012 04:04:34)
```

Comment: What about top? Are there tasks with 100% CPU usage or filling up your RAM!? Do you have swap? Is it actually used? By what processes? https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-which-process-is-using-swap/

Answer (score 0):

Try to profile the hung php-fpm process using `strace -p <PID_of_php-fpm process>`. You can also try to get stacktrace samples using `gdb`, more details [here](http://poormansprofiler.org/).